# Anyone know of an online resource with spritesheets from classic games?

Tags: 2d, graphics, sprites, spritesheet

I'm looking for spritesheets for classic retro games, and old home computer games (c64, amiga etc.) Does anyone know of a source online?

Comment: Be aware however that using such sprite-sheets is probably in contravention of copyright.

Comment: @Kylotan - that depends. There's a fuzzy divide between inspiration and a derivative work.

Comment: Yep. I just want the poster to be aware that this is an issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find free sprites and images?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/20/where-can-i-find-free-sprites-and-images)

Comment: @Josh: totally *not* a duplicate.

Comment: @Kylotan - thanks, but this is only for inspiration and my own interest, so shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I don't see how this question covers any ground that's significantly different or original, except to intrude upon potentially murky legal issues.

Answer (score 6):

http://spriters-resource.com/ has tons of different spritesheets from games.

Answer (score 2):

I like the first one the best.
http://www.videogamesprites.net/
http://www.retrogamezone.co.uk/nes.htm
http://www.spriters-resource.com/nes/A.html

Answer (score 1):

Google for "STOS sprites" and "AMOS sprites".

STOS and AMOS were basic variants for the Atari ST and Amiga respectively - both had large communities and there were a lot of sprite collections available in the public domain.

Also, try Googling for "TOSEC". There are some torrents (probably illegal) that collect virtually everything ever released for the Atari ST, the Amiga etc. That includes some large collections of public domain disks, some of which will contain sprite collections. If you're only looking to collect the PD stuff, you're probably on the right side of the law (if anyone cares anyway).

The big problem then is probably converting all those ancient file formats. It may be easier to view them in an emulator and get screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

This is not from old games but it sure has some sprites: http://www.reinerstilesets.de/

Comment: -1, there's a different question about good art resources for new games.

Comment: @joe: I honestly and really doesn't understand your point he asked for sprites and I answered to the best of my ability. Not an exact answer but still might prove useful. I guess you have not checked their sprites section. They are not from any old games but they do not violate any copyrights either. If he wants to make a game these might be a good substitute

Comment: He asked for sprites of old games. These are not sprites of old games. That settles it.